# Unable to generate the candle charts on dialog box in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a R shiny dashboard for stocks analysis. This dashboard has the date at top as driving criteria. The symbols are selected based on that.
The detailed information of these stocks are shown further one by one.
For demo purpose the data is displayed in the attached code.
One button is also added to the dashboard **for each of the symbol**.
On clicking the button the candle stick graph of that symbol is expected.

In present code when the button is clicked the graph is shown in the Plots pane of the RStudio and not in the graph..but error message subscript out of bounds is shown.
This is shown in the image .
Kindly suggest the changes to display the graph in the popup window.
[Image in Plot Pange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geYS1.jpg)

```r
    library(quantmod)
    library(shiny)
    
    getSymbols("AAPL",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("MSFT",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("META",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("ORCL",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("TSLA",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    getSymbols("GOOG",  from = "2020/01/01",to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
    df_AAPL <- as.data.frame(AAPL)
    df_AAPL$DATE <- index(AAPL)    
    rownames(df_AAPL) <- NULL
    names(df_AAPL) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_AAPL$SYMBOL <- 'AAPL'
    
    df_MSFT <- as.data.frame(MSFT)
    df_MSFT$DATE <- index(MSFT)    
    rownames(df_MSFT) <- NULL
    names(df_MSFT) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_MSFT$SYMBOL <- 'MSFT'
    
    df_META <- as.data.frame(META)
    df_META$DATE <- index(META)    
    rownames(df_META) <- NULL
    names(df_META) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_META$SYMBOL <- 'META'
    
    df_ORCL <- as.data.frame(ORCL)
    df_ORCL$DATE <- index(ORCL)    
    rownames(df_ORCL) <- NULL
    names(df_ORCL) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_ORCL$SYMBOL <- 'ORCL'
    
    df_TSLA <- as.data.frame(TSLA )
    df_TSLA$DATE <- index(TSLA)    
    rownames(df_TSLA) <- NULL
    names(df_TSLA) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_TSLA$SYMBOL <- 'TSLA'
    
    df_GOOG <- as.data.frame(GOOG)
    df_GOOG$DATE <- index(GOOG)    
    rownames(df_GOOG) <- NULL
    names(df_GOOG) <- c('OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED','DATE')
    df_GOOG$SYMBOL <- 'GOOG'
    
    df_all <- rbind(df_AAPL, df_MSFT,df_META,df_ORCL,df_TSLA,df_GOOG)
    df_all[, c('SYMBOL','DATE','OPEN','HIGH','LOW','CLOSE','VOLUME','ADJUSTED')]
    df_rep_date <- data.frame('RunDate'= character(),'ListStocks' = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    df_rep_date[1,] <-    c("2020-01-06", 'AAPL,GOOG,TSLA')
    df_rep_date[2,] <-    c("2021-01-04", 'ORCL')
    df_rep_date[3,] <-    c("2022-01-04", 'META,MSFT')
    #df_rep_date[4,] <-    c("2022-01-07", 'MSFT')
    df_rep_date$RunDate <- as.Date(df_rep_date$RunDate)
    v_lst_sel_dates <-c(df_rep_date$RunDate) 
    
    func_common_crt_lst <- function(...){ x <- list(...); return(x)}
    
    func_1symb_plot <- function(p_symb){
    df_tmp_hist_dat = df_all[df_all$SYMBOL == p_symb,c("DATE" ,"OPEN","HIGH","LOW" ,"CLOSE","VOLUME" )]
    v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts <-  xts(df_tmp_hist_dat[, -1], order.by = df_tmp_hist_dat[, 1])
    v_grph_op <- candleChart( v_df_dly_dat_6mnth_xts,name = p_symb, type = "auto", up.col = "green", dn.col = "red",
    theme = "white",plot = TRUE,TA = "addVo();addSMA(n = 1, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='black');
    addSMA(n = 7, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='gold'); addSMA(n = 14, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col ='brown');addMACD(); addBBands();addRSI();addOBV();")
    return(v_grph_op)}
    
    func_1symb_tab <- function(p_symb){
    df_tmp_hist_dat = df_all[df_all$SYMBOL == p_symb,c("DATE" ,"OPEN","HIGH","LOW" ,"CLOSE","VOLUME" )]
    df_tmp_hist_dat <- df_tmp_hist_dat[1:5,]
    df_tmp_hist_dat$DATE <- as.Date(df_tmp_hist_dat$DATE)
    v_tab_op <- df_tmp_hist_dat
    }
    
    
    simpUI <- function(id) {
    tagList(selectInput(NS(id, 'RunDate'), "Run Date", v_lst_sel_dates),
    textOutput(NS(id,'date_output')),
    textOutput(NS(id,'lst_symb_output')),
    uiOutput(NS(id,"myplot"))
    )
    }
    
    simpServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    string <- reactive(input$RunDate)
    output$date_output <- renderText(string())
    v_lst_symbol <- reactive(df_rep_date[df_rep_date$RunDate == input$RunDate,]$ListStocks)
    output$lst_symb_output <- renderText(v_lst_symbol())
    observeEvent(input$RunDate, {
    print(v_lst_symbol())
    symbs <- read.table(text = v_lst_symbol(), sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
    print(symbs)
    lapply(symbs[1,], function(v_symb){
    v_symb_name = paste0(v_symb, '_name')
    output[[paste0(v_symb, '_name')]] = renderText(v_symb_name)
    output[[paste0(v_symb, '_table')]] <- renderTable(func_1symb_tab(v_symb))
    observeEvent({input[[paste0(v_symb, '_cndl_chart')]]},{
    plt_cndl <- func_1symb_plot(v_symb)
    print(' before showModal')
    showModal(modalDialog(title = v_symb, size = "l",renderPlot(plt_cndl)))
    print("after showmodel   ")
    })
    })
    })
    
    output$myplot <- renderUI({
    symbs <- read.table(text = v_lst_symbol(), sep = ",", colClasses = "character")
    tagList(
    lapply(symbs[1,], function(v_symb){
    id1 <- paste0(v_symb, '_name')
    id3 <- paste0(v_symb, '_table')
    id4 <- paste0(v_symb, '_cndl_chart')
    fluidRow(
    func_common_crt_lst(htmlOutput(ns(id1)), 
    tableOutput(ns(id3)),
    actionButton(ns(id4), ns(id4))))
    })
    )
    })
    })
    }
    
    ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(simpUI("par1")))
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
    simpServer("par1")
    }
    shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That's hardly a *minimal* reproducible example.  None of the code to obtain your data is necessary: replace it with a simple reconstruction of a (small) fixed data frame. It's generally considered bad practice to conflate data input (`symbs <- read.table(...)`) with data presentation (`tagList(...)` etc).  Simplify, simplify!  If you do so, the problem may even become apparent without our help.

Comment: Its perspective. 
This is a simplified version of the problem. 
Intention is to give as complete the issue as possible(based on past experiences). 
This in turn will assist in getting the accurate intended solution. 
Since the application is complex, the problem statement is also detailed. **It will be great help if you can assist**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is by far **not** minimal and it needed quite some amount of time to strip all the unnecessary parts away to find out what you are trying. For future reference you may get more help if you minimize your code.

Your code has several issues:

1. You cannot use `renderPlot` without a corresponding `plotOutput`. That is the main issue why your plot does not show up. Hence, you need to place a `plotOutput` in your modal and add an additional `renderPlot` to fill it.
2. Your module is somewhat useless and you shoudl rather create a module around the elements *symbol name*, *table* and *modal action button*.
3. Using some loops helps tremendously to avoid this massive code duplictation.

Having said that, here's a working example which refactored your code quite extensively and made use of the `tidyverse` to simplify some of the data operations you are doing.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

get_data <- function(symbols = c("AAPL", "MSFT", "META", "ORCL",
                                 "TSLA", "GOOG")) {
   syms <- getSymbols(symbols, from = "2020/01/01", 
                      to = Sys.Date(), periodicity = "daily")
   map_dfr(syms, function(sym) {
      raw_data <- get(sym)
      raw_data %>%
         as_tibble() %>% 
         set_names(c("OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "VOLUME", "ADJUSTED")) %>% 
         mutate(SYMBOL = sym,
                DATE = index(raw_data)) %>% 
         select(SYMBOL, DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, ADJUSTED)
   })
}

if (!exists("df_all")) {
   df_all <- get_data()
}

df_rep_data <- tribble(~ RunDate, ~ ListStocks,
                       "2020-01-06", "AAPL, GOOG, TSLA",
                       "2021-01-04", "ORCL",
                       "2022-01-04", "META, MSFT") %>% 
   mutate(RunDate = as.Date(RunDate))

make_candle_chart <- function(symbol, dat = df_all) {
   vals <- dat %>% 
      filter(SYMBOL == symbol)
   ts <- xts(vals %>%  
                select(OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME),
             order.by = vals %>% pull(DATE))
   candleChart(ts, name = symbol, type = "auto",
               up.col = "green", dn.col = "red", theme = "white", plot = TRUE, 
               TA = c(addVo(),
                      addSMA(n = 1, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col = "black"),
                      addSMA(n = 7, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col = "gold"),
                      addSMA(n = 14, on = 1, overlay = TRUE, col = "brown"),
                      addMACD(),
                      addBBands(),
                      addRSI(),
                      addOBV()))
}

make_table <- function(symbol, dat = df_all) {
   dat %>% 
      filter(SYMBOL == symbol) %>% 
      select(DATE, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME) %>% 
      slice(1:5)
}

symb_ui <- function(id) {
   ns <- NS(id)
   tagList(
      tags$h4(textOutput(ns("symbol"))), 
      tableOutput(ns("table")), 
      actionButton(ns("show_modal"), "Show Candle Chart")
   )
}

symb_server <- function(id, get_symbol_name) {
   moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      output$symbol <- renderText(get_symbol_name())
      output$table <- renderTable(make_table(get_symbol_name()))
      output$cndl_chart <- renderPlot(make_candle_chart(get_symbol_name()))
      
      observeEvent(input$show_modal, {
         mdl <- modalDialog(title = get_symbol_name(), 
                            size = "l", 
                            plotOutput(ns("cndl_chart")))
         showModal(mdl)
      })
   })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
   selectInput("run_date", "Run Date", df_rep_data %>% pull(RunDate)),
   tags$h2(textOutput("date_output")), 
   tags$h3(textOutput("lst_symb_output")),
   uiOutput("symbols_output")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
   handler <- list()
   get_syms <- list()
   
   output$date_output <- renderText(req(input$run_date))
   output$lst_symb_output <- renderText({
      df_rep_data %>% 
         filter(RunDate == req(input$run_date)) %>% 
         pull(ListStocks)
   })
   
   output$symbols_output <- renderUI({
      symbols <- df_rep_data %>%
         filter(RunDate == req(input$run_date)) %>%
         pull(ListStocks) %>%
         str_split(fixed(", ")) %>%
         unlist()
      syms <- vector("list", length(symbols)) %>%
         set_names(symbols)
      for (sym in symbols) {
        ## this local construct is needed for scoping cf. 
        ## https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/e1ce7305f914f9ca762c69509dda632e
         local({ 
            my_sym <- sym
            syms[[my_sym]] <<- symb_ui(my_sym)
            get_syms[[my_sym]] <<- reactive(my_sym)
            handler[[my_sym]] <<- symb_server(my_sym, get_syms[[my_sym]])
         })
      }
      tagList(syms)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui =  ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks thothal!!!. The solution is very simple and elegant. I will definitely try to keep my code minimal in future while requesting help. I observed that your code involves good amount of short effective functions some of which I am coming across for first time. What would be good place to learn effective coding in R?

Comment: The solution provided by you was concise and precise. I'm extending the solution to include some tab pages....to provide the data exploration feature which will be dynamic. Can you suggest any book or documentation which I can use to develop shiny code along these lines.